# Cannot add foreign key constraint, composite PK and FK

Tags: sql, sqlfiddle

```
CREATE TABLE HOSPITAL (
  HOSP_CODE  INT(3) NOT NULL, 
  HOSP_NAME VARCHAR(15), 
  HOSP_ADDRESS VARCHAR(15), 
  HOSP_PHONE VARCHAR(8), 
  HOSP_SUMBED INT(5), 
  PRIMARY KEY (HOSP_CODE)
);

CREATE TABLE WARD (
  HOSP_CODE INT(3) NOT NULL,
  WARD_CODE INT(3) NOT NULL,
  WARD_NAME VARCHAR(20),
  WARD_SUMBED INT(3),
  PRIMARY KEY (HOSP_CODE, WARD_CODE),
  FOREIGN KEY (HOSP_CODE) REFERENCES HOSPITAL(HOSP_CODE),
  FOREIGN KEY (WARD_CODE) REFERENCES WARD(WARD_CODE)
);
```

I am trying to apply a constrain of a Primary Key that has 2 columns in it (HOSP_CODE and WARD_CODE) in table WARD and a Foreign Key constraint that is consisted of the two PK stated above.

Writing this code gives me the error stated in the title. 
I have searched quite a lot about this error but couldn't find anything.
I understand that if there is a composite PK then the FK that refers to the same keys needs to be composite. 
What I don't understand (and probably is the reason I have the error) is how can I assign the FK that refers to WARD_CODE.

Thank you in advance for your help and excuse me if I am unclear with my question.

P.S. I am new to SQL.

P.S2. The reason I need it this way is because of an assignment that a teacher gave us whose description mentions that table WARD should have a composite PK(HOSP_CODE,WARD_CODE) and two FKs for HOSP_CODE and WARD_CODE.

Comment: Is this using InnoDB with MySQL? If so, the problem is that any single column which serves as the referred-to column for a FK needs to be the *first* column of *some* index in the referred-to table. So you could create `WARD` with all but the `WARD_CODE` FK, then create an index on `WARD_CODE` in `WARD`, and *then* add the FK contraint you want on the single column of `WARD_CODE`.

Comment: Many times you get around this by just making a composite FK on the ordered columns for the de facto index (the primary key) of the table. But in your case, the requirement is explicitly for two single-column FKs, which means both of those things must, one way or another, be found as the first sorting column of some index on the table, be it the primary key or something else.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your first suggestion but for some reason another error comes out ('Error on rename of './db_9_1c173/#sql-7fa4_23b3' to './db_9_1c173/ward' (errno: 150 - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed)'). What I created the table    'WARD' without the FK, then using the CREATE INDEX command I created the index on 'WARD_CODE' and then added the FK with the ALTER TABLE command ( I mention the way I did it in case I did something wrong).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment.

I think you might want three tables:  `Hospitals`, `Wards`, and `HospitalWards`.

What you are calling `Ward` would be `HospitalWards`.  You need a second table with one row per `WardCode`.  I might think that the tables would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE WARDS (
  WARD_CODE INT(3) NOT NULL,
  WARD_NAME VARCHAR(20),
);

CREATE TABLE HospitalWards (
  HOSP_CODE INT(3) NOT NULL,
  WARD_CODE INT(3) NOT NULL,
  WARD_NUMBED INT(3),
  PRIMARY KEY (HOSP_CODE, WARD_CODE),
  FOREIGN KEY (HOSP_CODE) REFERENCES HOSPITALS(HOSP_CODE),
  FOREIGN KEY (WARD_CODE) REFERENCES WARDS(WARD_CODE)
);
```

The number of beds would be in the junction table.  Many hospitals might have maternity wards, for instance, but each would have a different number of beds.

Note that I tend to name tables in the plural rather than the singular.

Comment: The question suggests that this is a course assignment in which the instructor is requiring the `WARDS` table to have a self-referencing FK on the `WARD_CODE` column, probably specifically as a exercise to get right at this sort of FK creation error. It's unclear whether using an additional table (even if it would be the more pragmatic approach in real life) is permitted within the constraints of the assignment.

Comment: The description the teacher provided does not mention anything about an extra table. It states to create two tables (HOSPITAL and WARD), there is also a description file that shows all the tables that need to be created and there isn't anything about another table.